# Magento onepage checkout and account create not the same form

Tags: magento

Is it possible to get the fields from the onepage checkout (company name, vat id, address, ...) on the account creation page? (/customer/account/create)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates are by standard in the following places:

- `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml`
- `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml`

Now if the attribute has been set-up correctly then you simply add the attributes to the correct template, but the fields you have mentioned are actually part of the billing address and not the customer itself.

Now what you can do simply is set the address to show on registration via some layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
      <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>1</value></action>
    </reference>
  </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```